# Caching HTTP Authentication credentials for itms-services:// urls in Safari on iPad

Tags: ipad, safari, http-authentication, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an ad-hoc iPad app distribution server setup to allow users to download nightly builds of an iPad app through Safari, and I have Basic HTTP Authentication setup on the server.

When the user clicks the link to download the app, which looks something like this:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http%3A%2F%2F<url>
```

Safari is prompting the user to enter credentials every time. Is there a way to make it cache the credentials, like it does for normal `http://` pages?

Comment: did you find any solution to this? i'm facing the same problem!